# DateDiff of 2 dates in the same column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005 I need to get the `datediff` of 2 dates that are in the same column, table looks like this:

```
OrderNo    OpNo    ResType    LoadedStartDate
-----------------------------------------------------
12345      1       PAINT      2014-05-01 00:00:00.000
12345      2       PAINT      2014-05-02 00:00:00.000
12345      3       PAINT      2014-05-03 00:00:00.000
12345      4       ASMB       2014-05-04 00:00:00.000
67890      1       PAINT      2014-05-02 00:00:00.000
67890      2       PAINT      2014-05-03 00:00:00.000
67890      3       PAINT      2014-05-04 00:00:00.000
67890      4       ASMB       2014-05-05 00:00:00.000
```

I need to get the date diff of OpNo 1 and OpNo 4 where they are the same order number. The OpNo will always be 1 and 4 as the ones I am trying to compare, as will the ResType.

Output would need to look like this:

```
OrderNo    Difference
----------------------
12345      3
67890      3
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just join the table to itself:

```
SELECT t1.OrderNo,DATEDIFF(day,t1.LoadedStartDate,t2.LoadedStartDate)
FROM UnnamedTableFromQuestion t1
       INNER JOIN
     UnnamedTableFromQuestion t2
       on
         t1.OrderNo = t2.OrderNo
WHERE t1.OpNo = 1 and
      t2.OpNo = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty straightforward

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, 
         (SELECT LoadedStartDate FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo = 12345 AND OpNo = 1),
         (SELECT LoadedStartDate FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo = 12345 AND OpNo = 4)
       )
```

Since inner selects return scalar values - they can be used as parameters for DATEDIFF function

To make this work for all orders in a table you can do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderNo, DATEDIFF(day, 
          (SELECT LoadedStartDate FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo = Ord.OrderNo AND OpNo = 1),
          (SELECT LoadedStartDate FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo = Ord.OrderNo AND OpNo = 4)
       ) AS Diff
FROM Orders Ord
```

**Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc085/5**

Comment: Oooh, Lovely. Correlated subqueries and using `DISTINCT` to fudge the resource set. That query may have a few performance issues.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yup. Upvoted yours - very neat

Answer (score 0):

CTE works wonder in such scenarios. For your requirement, you can use the following query.

```
with op1
As
(
select orderno, opno, restype, LoadedStartDate From orders
where opno = 1
),
op4
As
(
select orderno, opno, restype, LoadedStartDate From orders
where opno = 4
)
select op1.orderno, datediff(day, op1.loadedstartdate, op4.loadedstartdate) DifferenceDays 
from op1 inner join op4 on op1.orderno = op4.orderno
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ORDERNO,MAX(DATEPART(DAY,LoadedStartDate))-MIN(DATEPART(DAY,LoadedStartDate))
FROM ORDERS GROUP BY ORDERNO
```

Mind you you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ORDERNO,MAX(LoadedStartDate)-MIN(LoadedStartDate) FROM ORDERS GROUP BY ORDERNO
```

Which returns 4 days in the datetime format; maybe because, with no times and due to the nature of MIN and MAX, the database assumes four whole days from the start of day one to the end of day 4.

If you do have order times and you want an exact time span between the first and last order, it might be possible to translate both datetimes into an integer which gives each in miliseconds, subtract the lower number from the higher number and then re-translate the answer back into the datetime format.