# How to return difference between timestamps in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I run a query on my table that makes it return timestamps in ascending order (oldest to newest). As in I put in a line `ORDER BY timestamp`.

I need my results to have a column called "Days Taken" which contains the difference between each of the timestamps, i.e. (Timestamp 2 - Timestamp 1), (Timestamp 3 - Timestamp 2), (Timestamp 4 - Timestamp 3) and so on. How do I do this using SQL?

```
value   timestamp             Days Taken
 2      2016-03-16 05:11:40    -
 3      2016-03-18 03:46:42    ?
 4      2016-03-18 04:09:44    ?
 5      2016-03-21 04:01:46    ?
 6      2016-03-22 04:38:17    ?
```

I'm unable to use the column `value` as an index because it is defined as a string and not an int which is why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937288/calculate-the-time-difference-between-of-two-rows) doesn't work for me. Days Taken is the value I'd like to calculate.

Edited to add: I'm running DbVisualizer for Vertica which does not seem to support subqueries in the ON clause.

Comment: Reading the manual would've shown you the [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function.

Comment: Yes, I should have been clearer. I'm aware of the function, but I'm not sure how to do a `DATEDIFF()` between multiple rows of the same query. A self-join?

Comment: What does your schema look like, then? Edit your question and add that if you can, it'll make what you want to do a lot clearer.

Comment: self-join indeed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366495/datediff-of-2-dates-in-the-same-column-sql

Comment: @tadman I've put that in, hope that makes it a bit clearer!

Answer (score 3):

Try something along these lines:

```
select datediff(dd, a.timestamp, b.timestamp)
  from #Table   a
  join #Table   b  on a.timeStamp = (select max(c.timeStamp) 
    from #Table c where c.timeStamp < b.timeStamp)
```

Comment: You've got three arguments in there for `DATEDIFF()` strangely.

Comment: I've tried versions of this but I get this weird error `Subqueries in the ON clause are not supported`.

Comment: @tadman and yes, that's allowed :) It tells the function to return the difference in days/weeks/hours/minutes and so on.

Comment: Where is that form documented? I couldn't find a reference to it.

Comment: @tadman [There](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/datediff.php) you go.

Comment: Read too quickly - this solution is for SQL Server, not sure if it will work on MySQL

Comment: @SeanCoetzee Yep! I'm running DbVisualizer for Vertica and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @geekchic MySQL usually has a small subset of what Postgres and SQL Server have, so be careful when checking your syntax.